# how to get Geojson co-ordinates of circle?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

currently we using code to draw a circle with marker,One question is any options available in your API to get geojson co-ordinates of circle? Please advise. This option is very useful for us.

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([<?=$lat?>, <?=$lng?>], 17);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1
    }).addTo(mymap);

    var myIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'logo_bg_icon.png',
        iconSize: [38, 95],
        iconAnchor: [22, 94],
        popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
        shadowSize: [68, 95],
        shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
    });

    let marker = L.marker([<?=$lat?>, <?=$lng?>], {icon : myIcon,draggable : true}).addTo(mymap);
    let circle = L.circle([<?=$lat?>, <?=$lng?>], {radius: 200}).addTo(mymap);

    marker.on('dragend', function(ev) {
        let latlng = marker.getLatLng();
        circle.remove();
        circle = L.circle(latlng, {radius: 200}).addTo(mymap);
        $('.lat').html("Lat: "+latlng.lat);
        $('.lng').html("Lng: "+latlng.lng);
    });
```

thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the circle as polygon or only the center point of a circle (default geojson of a circle)? For the center you can call `circle.getLatLng()`

Answer (score 0):

In generell you can get GeoJSON-Coordinates for each shape with `layer.toGeoJSON()`.

Also you can set the precision with `layer.toGeoJSON(number)`, default is 6

Answer (score 0):

Circle is not supported as a geometry in GeoJSON.

```
GeoJSON supports the following geometry types: Point, LineString, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiLineString, and MultiPolygon.
```

[https://geojson.org/](http://geojson.org)

However, you can :

1. get the center of the circle using `.getLatLng()` method and the radius of the circle *in meters*, using the `getRadius()` method.
2. get a circle-like polygon in GeoJSON format. For this, you can use `.circle()` method of Turf.js library (passing as parameters the center and radius from step 1) https://turfjs.org/docs/#circle